# Matching a number within a number in a python List

Tags: python

A queryset returned a list:

```
list1=[2856,28564,1245,232856]
```

When I try to find if a number exists in the above list by writing:

```
num=2856
if num in list1:
```

it matches 2856, 25564, and 232856. How can I make sure it matches only 2856 and not the rest?

Sorry I am new to Python, and could not find the solution. Apologies if I am asking a duplicate question.

Comment: _matches 2856, 25564, and 232856_ - no it does not, 2856 is equal only to first element in list.

Comment: Most probably the queryset is list of string not list of integers...that's why you got multiple matches.

Answer (score 3):

It does not behave like you suggest. In fact your current syntax gives your desired output.

```
>>> list1=[2856,28564,1245,232856]
>>> num=2856
>>> if num in list1:
...     print(num)
... 
2856
>>>
```

This is the behavior you are suggesting. Note how it is necessary to convert the integers to strings in this case.

```
>>> list1 = [2856,28564,1245,232856]
>>> num = 2856 
>>> [x for x in list1 if str(num) in str(x)]
[2856, 28564, 232856]
```

Answer (score 0):

For your specific example:

[x for x in list1 if x==2856][0]

returns a single element list containing only the value you want and you access its only position to get the element.

Answer (score -1):

You are checking if the value of num is inside of the list. Therefore, the expression

```
num in list1
```

is True if num is equal to any item of list1. To make it only True when num is equal to the first (here: 2856) you have to write:

```
num == list1[0]
```